# using a= b and a= !!b in javascript and the differences between them

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to try the difference between using Direct assigning and assigning with !!

```
var a = true,
    b = true;
a = b;
alert(a);
a = !!b;
alert(a);
```

does it have difference in using or result
i can't compare each of their result

Comment: There's no difference in the result in that particular case of yours. When `a` and `b` are not booleans, the difference will occur. The double `!` is used to convert values to boolean.

Comment: Is the statement on line 5 correct: (a = !!b)? Are you trying to asign the value of variable b to a or tryinh to compare the two variables?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, *per se*. But  `a = !!b` is slightly less efficient, I believe.
Since, first it's converted to `false` and again converted to `true`.

Don't know if this is a case of *micro-optimization*, but `a = b` would be the straight-forward way and more readable.

Comment: so it just a different in efficient
and there is no touchable difference

Answer (score 1):

`!!x` is commonly used as a shortcut for `Boolean(x)`. I just ran a little test and the double negation has exactly zero performance cost. Even when the assigned value is not a constant and even when it is not a Boolean to begin with. Boolean conversion is so simple that it's basically free.

Answer (score 1):

It's not different. The result will be the same as that of a direct comparison.

The use case for using !! is: 
Many times it happens that you want to check a non-boolean against a boolean value or check whether a value is true or false inside an if condition. This is exactly when you would want to use !!.

What !! does is, it first negates the value of the variable and then again negates the value obtained in the previous negation.

Say for e.g. if you use it like this:

```
var str = "";
console.log(!!str);
```

This would give you the boolean value of false.

You should use !! When you are required to do a strict check for truthness of a condition.
Something like this:

```
if (true === !!str) {
    console.log('true');
} else {
    console.log('false');
}
```